# MSSQL Return 0 for null blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select COALESCE([ItemSlotX],0) as [ItemSlotX],COALESCE([ItemSlotY], 0 ) as [ItemSlotY] from [PowerUP_Items] where [ItemIndex]=16 and [ItemGroup]=255
```

In my case, is no record.

How can I return 0 for ItemSlotX and 0 for ItemSlotY if there is no record found?

Comment: What datatype is ItemSlotX and ItemSlotY?

Comment: When you say blank\empty do you mean you are getting no rows back?

Comment: Datatype of columns is int.

Comment: You are not getting back any rows because your 'Where' clause is filtering them all out. Can you post some example data in the table?

Comment: Yes datatype is int, i delete de ''. My problem is now about what query result returned, only if the record selected don't match, i need to return me 0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results, even when there is no matching row, use this:

```
select COALESCE([ItemSlotX],0) as [ItemSlotX],COALESCE([ItemSlotY], 0 ) as [ItemSlotY]
from (select null dummy ) d
left
outer
join [PowerUP_Items]
on   [ItemIndex]=16 and [ItemGroup]=255
```

Comment: I know about the result, but my question is: if this query have result (no records/empty) how i can tell to sql to return me 0 on both fields.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
select ItemSlotX, ItemSlotY from PowerUP_Items where ItemIndex=16 and ItemGroup=255
if @@rowcount = 0
    select 0 as ItemSlotX, 0 as ItemSlotY
```

Or more general approach:

```
if exists (select * from PowerUP_Items where ItemIndex=16 and ItemGroup=255)
    select ItemSlotX, ItemSlotY from PowerUP_Items where ItemIndex=16 and ItemGroup=255
else
    select 0 as ItemSlotX, 0 as ItemSlotY
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query must return not more than one row, try this

```
select COALESCE(max([ItemSlotX]),0) as [ItemSlotX],COALESCE(max([ItemSlotY]), 0 ) as [ItemSlotY] 
from [PowerUP_Items] where [ItemIndex]=16 and [ItemGroup]=255
```